# overflow-x cutting off absolutely positioned child

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

In [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/siwasaga/1/edit), the absolutely positioned green `<div>` is being cut off at the top when I set `overflow-x: auto` on the parent element. Why? From my understanding, `overflow-y` is still `visible`, so the overflow should be visible.

```
#red {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}
#green {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
  top: -5px;
}

<div id="red">
  <div id="green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this that explains your situation: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

"According to the spec ... some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’"

and

"In Gecko, Safari, Opera, ‘visible’ becomes ‘auto’ also when combined with ‘hidden’ (in other words: ‘visible’ becomes ‘auto’ when combined with anything else different from ‘visible’). Gecko 1.8, Safari 3, Opera 9.5 are pretty consistent among them."

Hope it helps.